# read_html() is not geting NES stock website's HTML in R

Tags: r, rvest

I have been trying to scrape TATAMOTORS stock price from NSE(National Stock Exchange) website in R using package `rvest`. I create a variable `nes_link` store URL of the website in it. and make another variable nes_page and assign `read_html(nes_link)` in it but no response in there in the console.

**CODE**

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

nes_link <- "https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes/equity?symbol=TATAMOTORS"

nes_page <- read_html(nes_link)

price_day1 <- nes_page %>% 
  html_nodes("span#quoteLtp") %>% 
  html_text()`
```

Comment: Look at [robot.txt](https://www.nseindia.com/robots.txt),  scraping may not be allowed. Instead try `RSelenium`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the website uses JavaScript and `rvest` does not, you should
use `RSelenium`:

In your Shell:

```
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -p 7900:7900 --shm-size="2g" selenium/standalone-firefox
```

Then in R:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(RSelenium)

remDr <- remoteDriver$new(
  remoteServerAddr = "localhost",
  port = 4444
)

remDr$open()

remDr$navigate("https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes/equity?symbol=TATAMOTORS")

remDr$findElement("span#quoteLtp", using = "css")$getElementText()[[1]] %>%
as.numeric()
```

Please check if web scraping is allowed at this website.